# Best structure to be able to access an itemized list.

Tags: c++

I need to be able to populate a list one time and then return the index of the item quickly. For instance if I had 10 people in a list i need to be able to look up the person and return their number(1-10) in the list. I thought about several different ways but so far none have worked. I have a vector populated with my data now I just need to be able to get to the index. I am not set on a vector though if anyone has a better idea I am more than willing to listen. 
Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow.

For a list that small, it doesn't really matter. Generally though you are going to get better lookup times from ordered collections. I would suggest [std::set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/). If that doesn't work in your scenario (e.g. you want to determine the order yourself) then [std::map](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/) may be better.

Edit*

As you clarified in your comment, all you want is the index from a vector, then I would do something like this.

```
int main() {
    vector<string> v;
    vector<string>::iterator it;

    v.push_back("a");
    v.push_back("b");
    v.push_back("c");
    v.push_back("d");

    it=find(v.begin(),v.end(),"c");

    if(it!=v.end()){
        int index = distance(v.begin(), it);
        cout<<"found "<<index<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"not found"<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry if my formatting is strange, I'm not really a cpp programmer

Comment: I guess what I am asking is how I would return the index number? which is what I actually need. Sorry I wasn't clear. I am new to this and cant figure out how to get to the index value. It really seems so simple but I don't know why this is giving me such a hard time. I have  been at it for literally hours.Is there a way to look something up in a vector and get its index? or would map or set be better and I should start over? Thanks again.

Comment: If the list is ordered, you can do a binary search on a `std::vector` faster than a linear search.